# piping strings from program output

Tags: command-line, pipe

I have a program that outputs data continuously 3 or 4 lines at a time (sometimes the 4th line is a status update).  I want to keep only the 2nd (begins with "cmd: ") and 3rd lines (begins with "prc: "), then get rid of those first 5 characters for the final output.  Is there any way to do this via windows command line?  I have so far:

```
 program.exe -flags | FINDSTR /c:"cmd" /c:"prc" |  WHAT???? > "output.txt"
```

Even better yet, is there a way to replace the newline characters (in addition to deleting the first 5 characters) with a comma so that the output has the two value pairs (cmd and prc) on the same line?

Thanks for any help.

ALSO: is there any way to split the output on the fly between multiple files such that no one file is greater than say 10MB or 10,000 lines, etc?  eg when "output01.txt" hits 10K lines, start sending output to "output02.txt", and so on?

Comment: all of this is a thousand times easier using the Unix/Linux tool set. There are several work-alikes that you can install on Windows, or it is easy enough to run a Virtual Machine on Windows that gives you a really complete Linux environment. Cygwin, mingw are 2 mature work-a-likes. I can't give you a name for a VM linux to install. I'm sure others can. good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution (**edited:** it doesn't append the two lines into one line), but for the second part the `program.exe` will have to be stopped and restarted to change the `output filename`.

This uses a helper batch file called `repl.bat` - download from:  https://www.dropbox.com/s/qidqwztmetbvklt/repl.bat

Place `repl.bat` in the same folder as the batch file or in a folder that is on the path.

```
program.exe -flags | repl "^(cmd|prc): " "" a >output.txt
```

Comment: The M option may not work if the program runs continuously since REPL.BAT must buffer the entire input until end-of-file if using the M option.

Comment: But REPL.BAT cannot search for `\n` without the `M` option - a bit of a catch 22. I don't see a good solution for the newline problem using REPL.BAT if the program runs continuously.

Comment: @dbenham Thanks again.  It will remove the leading 5 characters easily though.  That's what I intended with my earlier edit but wasn't on the ball.

Comment: There is a simpler way - `program.exe -flags | repl "^(cmd|prc): " "" a >output.txt`

Comment: @dbenham mucho better.  I replaced my answer with it.

Answer (score 0):

Windows batch is not a very good option for your full set of requirements. It could be solved easily with many other scripting languages, for example VBScript, JScript, PowerShell. There may be Windows ports of unix utils that might also make the job easier.

But I did manage to come up with an efficient native batch solution. It requires that the program output is redirected to a temporary file, and then the logging script reads from that file. The only real drawback is that the logging script polls for input in a tight loop.

**LOGGER.BAT**

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
if "%~1" == ":process:" goto :process

set file=0
set "maxLines=%~2"
if not defined maxLines set "maxLines=10000"
for /l %%. in () do (
  set /a file+=1
  set suffix=00!file!
  set suffix=!suffix:~-3!
  cmd /c ^""%~f0" :process: ^>"%~dpn1!suffix!%~x1"^" || exit
)

:process
set "cnt=0"
set "cmd="
for /l %%. in () do (
  set "ln="
  set /p "ln="
  if defined ln (
    if "!ln:~0,5!" equ "[END]" exit 1
    if defined cmd (
      (echo !cmd!,!ln:~5!)
      set "cmd="
      set /a cnt+=1
      if !cnt! geq !maxLines! exit 0
    ) else if "!ln:~0,5!" equ "cmd: " set "cmd=!ln:~5!"
  )
)
```

LOGGER.BAT expects two arguments: 1) the base name of the output file(s), and 2) the maximum number of lines in each output file. If the given output file is "output.txt", then the logger will create "output001.txt", "output002.txt", etc.

I assume your program will eventually end, either on its own, or via some external trigger. LOGGER.BAT needs a way to know when the input is exhausted. It will terminate when it sees an input line that begins with `[END]`.

Here is how the logger would be called:

```
(program.exe -flags & echo [END]) >logger.tmp | <logger.tmp LOGGER.BAT output.txt 10000
```